# How to save a calculated column in SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I would like to know how to save a calculated value in a clean way in the database:

An example (taken from the SQLAlchemy manual):

```py
Base = declarative_base()

class Interval(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'interval'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    start = Column(Integer)
    end = Column(Integer)

    @hybrid_property
    def length(self):
        return self.end - self.start
```

So `length` is calculated. But for easier query look-ups (in another database tool), I would like to have this `length` saved as well into the table.

So my first crude test was to simply add: `length = Column(Float)`. Obviously this doesn't work (but I thought I would try it nevertheless :p) as the length-method overwrites the length-Column.

Right now my only way I can think of is to calculate it in the init & defer to super(), like this:

```py
Base = declarative_base()

class Interval(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'interval'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    start = Column(Integer)
    end = Column(Integer)
    length = Column(Integer)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        kwargs['length'] = kwargs['end'] - kwargs['start']
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

However, I feel there should be a cleaner way. Is there?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's several ways to handle this.

One is with [`before_update`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/events.html#sqlalchemy.orm.events.MapperEvents.before_update) and `before_insert` triggers. These are a SQLAlchemy thing where changes to a model are detected automatically, and events are dispatched before the rows are written to the server. You can then use that to pre-empt the save, potentially see which columns have changed, and then update `length` accordingly.

Another one is using `generated` or `computed column`. These have been introduced in [Postgres 12](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/ddl-generated-columns.html), and they're also present in MySQL, Oracle, and MS SQL Server - although I know less about that.
They do essentially the same thing, but you just add that logic to your table definition and you're free to forget about it. SQLAlchemy supports them as of [1.3.11](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/defaults.html#computed-ddl).

Comment: Your second will not work sadly enough as I'm using SQLite :). The first one gave me a good hint. I first tried before_insert, but that wasn't good as I needed the level to be read too. Next was init_scalar, but that didn't trigger during insert. So I ended up using "init". Modifying the kwargs on the init handler did what I needed it to do. The major concern I'm having with this is that it separates the initialization from the class itself. So thinking if it is truly worth the trouble ;-).

Answer (score 1):

You may use `Computed` column as written in [sqlalchemy/**init**.py line 65](https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/blob/main/lib/sqlalchemy/__init__.py)

You can use it like this:

```
from sqlalchemy import Column, Computed, Integer, ForeignKey

class Order(Base):
  item_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("item.id"), primary_key=True)
  unit_price = Column(Integer, nullable=False)
  quantity = Column(Integer, nullable=False)
  total_amount = Column(Integer, Computed(unit_price * quantity))  # this is computed column
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **[column_property](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/mapped_sql_expr.html#using-column-property)** feature in sqlalchemy instead **hybrid_property**.

**column_property**: The column_property() function can be used to map a SQL expression in a manner similar to a regularly mapped Column. With this technique, the attribute is loaded along with all other column-mapped attributes at load time.

Note:also you can `query` on **column_property**.

```py
Base = declarative_base()

class Interval(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'interval'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    start = Column(Integer)
    end = Column(Integer)
    length = column_property(end - start)
```

**query example:**

```py
session.query(Interval).filter(Interval.length == 10)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your contribution, but `length` as described by you, is not saved into the database.